# How can I use py2exe with the OSGeo4W Python installation?

Tags: python, osgeo, py2exe

I have a default Python installation in c:\Python27. I have also installed Python through the OSGeo4W installer, which has created a "sandboxed" Python installation with all the geospatial bindings I need. Now, I need to package a script using py2exe, but I can't figure out how to install or configure py2exe to work with the OSGeo4W installation. I have configured OSGeo4W to [install external packages with pip](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki/ExternalPythonPackages), but py2exe doesn't seem to install with pip. If I try to use the downloaded installer, it only finds the system install in the registry. Any ideas how to get it working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had better luck with [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org) than [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/). It pretty much works out of the box for me with o4w python (you may need to install the optional `python-win32` package). Follow the [install instructions](http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/v2.0/project/doc/Manual.html?format=raw#installing-pyinstaller), and run the Build step. I didn't need to get into manually altering the spec file or even using options (other than `--onefile` for end user simplicity). Just make sure you run from inside the o4w shell so pyinstaller finds the right python environment. [Here](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/browser/trunk/apt/BuildAptExe.bat) is my pyinstaller build batch file. There is only one line that does the real work:

```
python pyinstaller.py --onefile --out=%path\to\distrib%\myexe-%rev% %path\to\my\file.py%
```

Not to say py2exe can't work, it's just been so long now I no longer remember where I ran into difficulties with it or what the possible solution routes were.

Comment: Thanks, matt, this is a good alternative option and I'll give it a try.

Comment: I ran into a snag with this approach: pyinstaller needs pywin32 to work on Python 2.6+. Fortunately it can be installed using the o4w setup program.

Comment: I added note re: python-win32 requirement, thanks rudi

Comment: As a followup, I managed to create the exe without any problems using this method. When it came to running the executable, I kept getting `ImportError: No module named _gdal`. I thought it was a problem with the pyinstaller hooks, but it seems it's actually an environment issue in OSGeo4W, since I could get it to work fine from a regular `cmd` prompt (ie not o4w shell) as long as the `GDAL_DATA` environment variable is set. I wrote more on this at [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698348/cant-get-pyinstaller-hooks-to-work-with-gdal).

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get py2exe to work using a suggestion from **wildintellect** on IRC. After installing py2exe on the system python, I checked the install log (`c:\Python27\py2exe-wininst.log`) and copied the files into the o4w python installation (`c:\OSGeo4W\apps\python27\lib`). Basically, that meant the following files and directories:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\py2exe-0.6.9-py2.7.egg-info
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\zipextimporter.py
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\_memimporter.pyd
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\py2exe
```

I also had to copy these DLLs into `C:\OSGeo4W\apps\python27\DLLs` to get it to link properly (basically I searched the c:\windows directory and copied across whatever caused it to fail):

```
msvsp90.dll
msvcr80.dll
```

There may be reasons why this is a bad idea, but if you are set on using py2exe, then this seems to work.

Comment: 2 days...good to know. Also, no matter who gets the credit, at least we all have another osgeo4w problem solved! I am sure you are not the only one who wants to use py2exe.

Answer (score 2):

one option would be to add the osgeo python to your windows registry:
http://effbot.org/zone/python-register.htm

this site also contains information on how to remove it from the registry if you so desire.

I am pretty sure this will help you as long as you have admin rights to the registry.

Comment: Thanks, that would work, except for the following: "Note that there can be only one registered interpreter for each major Python release (e.g. 2.0, 2.1, 2,2 etc)"
Both are 2.7

Comment: I was envisioning using it temporarily. ie. taking the C:\python version out of registry and using osgeo\python and then switching back later...best I could think of :)

Comment: Please see [add/remove the o4w python to/from Windows registry](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/114) on osgeo4w website for an improved version of the effbot recipe, made specifically for o4w.

Comment: I should have looked there first! thanks mattwilkie